# How to prevent a GCE Kubernetes pod from working on a GPU instance?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gpu, kubectl

I use Google Cloud Platform for my project.
Now, I have a cluster with 4 node pools:
- "micro-pool": with minimal machines for managing the cluster
- "cpu-pool": with cpu-only machines for processes that don't need a GPU
- 2 "gpu-pools": two pools with machines that have GPUs attached.

Now, what I need is for my CPU processes to never work on a GPU machine because they take so much time and doing that on a GPU machine is just costing money for nothing.
I run my pods using the
`kubectl run dc-1 --image={image-name} --replicas=1 --restart=Never --limits="nvidia.com/gpu=0,cpu=4000m,memory=2Gi" -- bash -c "command to execute"`

Now, this works fine if there were no "GPU-machines" created from previous GPU runs. But if there was a very recent GPU run, this command will run on that instance because it has the minimum cpu and memory requirements. I thought the `--limits="nvidia.com/gpu=0` would do the trick but obviously it didn't.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to assign the pod on particular instance or node you can use the kubernetes node selector

for example :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    env: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  nodeSelector:
    disktype: ssd
```

here it will assign pod based on the node selector which is disk type.

you can also check this url for further documentation : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node

**Edit 1** :

as you are on GCP you can use this way also :

```
nodeSelector:
        #<labelname>:value
        cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: pool-highcpu8 (poolname)
```

**Edit 2** :

if you have knowledge of `affinity` and `anity-affinity` you can implement it also.

```
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/node-type
            operator: In
            values:
            - gpu
```

For cpu :

```
spec:
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 100
        podAffinityTerm:
          labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: resources
              operator: In
              values:
              - cpu-only
```

Comment: So, I tried running the command like this: 
`kubectl run dc-1 --image={image-name} --replicas=1 --restart=Never --limits="nvidia.com/gpu=0,cpu=4000m,memory=2Gi" --overrides='{"apiVersion": "v1", "spec": {"nodeSelector": { "cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool": "cpu-pool" }}}' -- bash -c "command to execute"` But I get this error: "Cannot schedule pods: node(s) didn't match node selector."

Comment: I guess it is searching in the currently running nodes. It is not scheduling new nodes from the node-pool I specified.

Comment: Sorry, it worked. I just had a wrong number for CPU resource.

Comment: @Ahmedn1 glad to hear that

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use case for [taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/). You can taint the GPU nodes with NoSchedule. This will prevent pods (even system pods) that don't have a toleration for that taint from running on the GPU nodes

```
kubectl taint nodes gpuNode1 nodetype=gpu:NoSchedule
```

Then, on pods you do want to run on these nodes, you can add a toleration for the taint:

```
tolerations:
- key: "nodetype"
  operator: "Equal"
  value: "gpu"
  effect: "NoSchedule"
```

I'm not sure on GCP, but on Azure's AKS you can configure the taint when you create the cluster and the node pools.

Edit:

You will want to combine this with Harsh Manvar's sugestion of node selectors and/or affinity. Just because your pod can tolerate the taint, doesn't mean it will be scheduled on the GPU nodes for sure, it will just make sure other things are not.